# How to move a cube 3 second in one direction, and next 3 seconds in oppposite direction, alternatively

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity, and trying something like below, but I can either move only in one direction, or not moving at all.

My cube is a trigger, and is not using gravity. I have checked the Kitematic box. I am trying to make the cube move to and fro, so that player have difficuly collecting it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class movedanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int mytime = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MyMover(mytime);
    }

    void MyMover(int mytime)
    {
      if (mytime <= 3)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
            mytime++;
        }

        else
        {
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
            mytime = 1;
        }
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Welcome new user!  Definitely don't use an int here for any reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is to and fro movement of an object. You can achieve this with `Mathf.PingPong()` function instead of using translate. I have tested it with a cube, you can set the minimum and maximum distance it should move to and the speed at which it travels. Since you want the cube to move 3 seconds in one direction at a time. You can calculate the speed as distance/time so the max distance it should travel to from the current distance and the time (3 seconds) it takes. Hope this helps.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCube : MonoBehaviour {
    public float min = 2f;
    public float max = 8f;
    public float SpeedOfMovement = 2f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (Mathf.PingPong (Time.time * SpeedOfMovement, max - min) + min, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }


}
```

Comment: This is 1000000% correct and what an expert would do.  BUT for a beginner, a beginner should learn about simple timer commands, so, Invoke and InvokeRepeating.

Comment: @Fattie yeah you are right. The user Lotan has explained with InvokeRepeating() so the OP would feel easier to go with that for now.

Comment: Completly agree, your explanation is more advanced @Saif, but also more correct, good catch!

Comment: In reality , us three guys would just do it with a spring and physics so it looks cool, but, we're here to help new users !!  :ppp  heh !

Comment: @Lotan what I would probably do there.  I usually make such components work only on the >> local << position.  So imagine you have something like say "the floor" of the room.  As a child of that, I would have "movingCube".  That would just be an empty game object.  I could move that around anywhere I want the "bouncy cube" to be. Then as a child of that would be my "cube" WITH a script attached which moves it back-and-fore by changing the *local* position.  Then you can easily move movingCube (the "whole thing") anywhere you want.

Comment: @Fattie Thanks, I get it, but why all this stuff, instead of just tweak the global position? This way it won't depend on the local space, so if there are more parents on the top, won't be affected, no?

Comment: @Lotan - for sure, what you say is totally correct.  However it's really easy to work in local space, and then you can use it on anything at all.  Also, say in the future you changed the way the mechanism works (perhaps using a spring, easing, an animation, or whatever).  Then you would *only change that component*, you wouldn't have to change "movingCube" at all.  "movingCube" itself would likely have other components (arrivals, departures, explosions, sound, etc etc etc) so it's often handy to *separate* out these functions.

Answer (score 1):

With `InvokeRepeating` you will call the same MoveCube method every 3 seconds.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveDanger: MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isForward = false;

    private void Start()
    {
      
        InvokeRepeating("MoveCube", 0f, 3f);
    }

    private void MoveCube()
    {
        if (isForward)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.back);
            isForward = false;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward);
            isForward = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the **best and easiest** way to do something like this, once you get used to it, is just to

## Use Unity's incredibly simple animator system:

[image]

(Essentially just click "new animation" and then drag the object around as you want it animated.)

There are 100s of tutorials online explaining how to use it.

It's one of those things where once you use it and see how easy it is, you will do a "facepalm" and never bother again with other ways.

It's really "the Unity way" to achieve the goal here, dead easy and flexible.